# Retrieve specific column of data and store it in string array

Tags: android, sqlite, arrays

I got a sqlite database and i wanted to retrieve a specific column of data and store it into a string array. Inside the database there are two columns. There will be multiple row of data with the same username and I wanted to retrieve the user's "ContentPath" and store it into a string array. But I don't know how to retrieve that specific column data...

```
    public String[] get_contentByEmailID(String emailid){
    String[] returnMsg = null;
    helper = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = helper.rawQuery("SELECT tableid, emailid, contentpath" +
            " from w_content where emailid='"+emailid"' ", null);



    int contentpathColumn = c.getColumnIndex("contentpath");


    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            returnMsg = new String[2]; 

            String contentpath = c.getString(contentpathColumn);

            returnMsg[0] = emailid_sync;

            returnMsg[1] = contentpath;


        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
        c.close();
    }
    if (helper!=null){
        helper.close();
    };
    return returnMsg;
}
```

When I called this function to retrieve the data. It comes up with emailid and contentpath.

```
String values[] = helper.get_contentByEmailID(SettingConstant.EMAIL);
```

Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you got array filled with emailid and contentpath is, because you always reset the `returnMsg` on each row and fill it with such value. Since there will be varying row count, it is generally suggested that you use `ArrayList`, instead of building static length array.

To fix it, change:

```
String[] returnMsg = null;
```

to:

```
ArrayList<String> returnMsg = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then, in your `do{}`, do something like this:

```
do {
    String contentpath = c.getString(contentpathColumn);
    returnMsg.add(contentpath);
} while (c.moveToNext());
```

Finally, change your return statement to:

```
return returnMsg.toArray();
```

Comment: I got one more question. In the end my function turned into public Object[] get_content(String emailid). What does Object[] different from normal array?

Comment: `Object[]` notation mean that it is an array of Object. `[]` mean array. So, String[] mean an array of String and so on. Read here for more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html | `Object` is the parent of all object in Java.